# Multiple attachments columns in SharePoint lists

Tags: sharepoint, list, attachment

What I need is to clearly differentiate between the attachments (this is an approval, this is an offer, this is a PO, etc).
Is this possible, or it is working only in bulk (attach all files together)?

Thanks,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could create separate lists for each item requiring an attachment, then link those lists in a master table.

Comment: SharePoint does not have "tables" (at least, not available to us, you are not supposed to tamper with the SharePoint Content Databases. EVER). It has lists. dahlbyk provided the correct answer.

Comment: Thanks,
I dropped the idea. Will just use the regular attachement option SharePpoint provides.

Answer (score 11):

SharePoint does not support attachment metadata. I would suggest storing the attachments in a document library (probably with Content Types for Approval, Offer, PO, etc) with a lookup column to the associated item in your list.

Comment: Thanks,
I dropped the idea. Will just use the regular attachement option SharePpoint provides.

Answer (score 1):

There are two option.

1. Add as many attachment you want to attachment column with the list. but you cannot associate metadata with that.
2. Create document library and use lookup in the list to view name of the document. so in a way it is storing the common document in library and just refer which one you are supposed to use.

Custom code is another one.