# Sharepoint or PowerApps - how add multiple doc links in a List to a document list

Tags: sharepoint, powerapps

I have different document types that need to go in different columns of my Sharepoint List.  How do I add multiple links per column/row to specific documents in their list?

My **Main List** looks like this:

```
ProductType   ProductPart    Country    RegDocTypeA        RegDocTypeB        OtherDoc
Cabinet       PartA          USA;DEU    DocA1URL;DocA2URL  DocB1URL;DocB2URL  Note1URL
...
```

**DocLibraries**:

```
*RegulatoryDocTypesA*
Title    Attachment      Expiration
DocA1    DocA1(Attached)  12/1/2023
DocA2    DocA2(Attached)  12/2/2024

*RegulatoryDocTypesB*
Title    Attachment      Expiration
DocB1    DocB1(Attached)  12/1/2025
DocB2    DocB2(Attached)  12/3/2026

*OtherDocList*
Title    Attachment      Expiration
Note1    Note1(Attached)  
Note2    Note2(Attached)
```

How do I get these links attached in my Main List, that point to each document in the DocumentLists?  I can't have just one Attachment column in my Main List, because the documents are categorized and have different expirations. I think the best way to do this is a live link to the document in the separate document libraries from the main list. But I can't find a good example or video how to do it. I'd like to populate the title automatically with the document name in the document library so it's visible in the selection combo.

I was looking at [multiple attachments](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/315372/how-to-add-multiple-attachments-in-sharepoint-info.html), and [attachments](https://powerapps.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/add-attachments-to-sharepoint-lists/), and [multiple attachment columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1184024/multiple-attachments-columns-in-sharepoint-lists), and [file title with filename](https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Building-Flows/Fill-the-file-title-in-sharepoint-with-the-filename/td-p/635898), and [title with name](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/200956/how-to-populate-title-column-with-name-column-content).

This is with sharepoint 365. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works now. Sorry I can't add pictures, since I'm only 100/new member.

Added in Power Apps, a new field . Deleted the input field, added combo box input. This has been set up in sharepoint as a column of lookup type, with the source list as the doc library RegulatoryDocTypeA, and allows multiple selections.

The doc library needed these changes:

1. Add title in doc library through all documents menu, edit current view, chooose title...

   ```
   a. In doc library, choose integrate->power automate->see your flows. 
   b. New flow+, automated cloud flow, give it a flow name, when a file is created or modified (properties) sharepoint. 
   c. site address: your link, library: regulatoryDocTypesA, last one blank for folder (+new step)
   d. control; condition; choose value first one: title, is equal to: name
   e. in the "if no" box: add action; search for: update file properties; sharepoint; update file properties. 
   f. Address: your link; library: RegulatoryDocTypeA; id:id; title: search - filename with extension; save.
   g. ctrl f5; delete files if already in doc library. Drag files in again. It takes a while to populate title with name.
   h. This doesn't link to the file yet. Just gives a choice.
   ```
2. Add link to doc library for RegulatoryDocTypeA doc added, so it's in main list and can see doc if select it.

   ```
   a. In RegulatoryDocTypeA doc library, go to settings; library settings; form settings; modify in power apps.
   b. Add button with insert at the top (make sure it's on form screen 1, which is outer form selected)
   c. select button so it's highlighted. In formula field, add Launch(SharePointIntegration.Selected.'Link to item')
   ```